# When message process fails, can consumer put back message to same topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose one of my program consuming message from kafka topic. During processing of message, consumer access some db. Its db acccess fails due to xyz reason. But we dont have to abandon the message. We need to park the message for later processing. In JMS when message processing fails application container put back the message to the queue. It does not lost. In Kafka once it received its offset increases and next message comes. How to handle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to achieve this.

1. Set the Kafka Acknowledge mode to `manual` and in case of error terminate the consumer thread without submitting the offset (If group management is enabled new consumer will be added after triggering re balancing and poll the same batch)
2. Second approach is simple, just have one error topic and publish messages to error topic in case of any error, so later you can consumer them or keep track of them.